# no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application when trying to enable push notifications

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5, urbanairship.com

I've been reading all the other questions asking about this error and it seems like I've followed their solutions but I'm still having this problem. I removed all the existing provisioning profiles and app ids. I created a new app id that has push enabled. I created a development provisioning profile with push enabled. On the Apple dev site, that provisioning profile has a green "active" indicator next to it. In xcode5, under preferences>accounts, the provisioning profile is listed. Under window>organizer, the provisioning profile appears under my device with the status "valid profile". But the error is still occurring. What am I missing here?

Edit: I want to make it clear that I created my provisioning profile AFTER creating the APNS certificate since that seems to be the most common solution to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course I figure out what's wrong right after typing a question - the bundle identifier in xcode did not match my appid, and I forgot to update the certificate I uploaded to urban airship after restarting the configuration process.

Comment: In my case, my bundle identifier was fine, but my Team was blank. Setting this fixed the issue.

Comment: Had to upvote bsegraves, made me look at Team.  I have a personal developer account and also belong to a client's team.  Turns out I had the wrong account chosen.  Thanks bsegraves!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you fixed the issue, but I got this issue when I moved to a new machine.  Turns out I forgot to bring some certificates from my old machine.  I fixed it by importing certificates from old to new.

Steps are:

1. Export certs on old machine as .p12.
2. Copy them to new machine.
3. Double click on file(s) to put them in Keychain Access on new
   machine.
4. In Xcode on your new machine, go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts, then
   refresh the provisioning profiles.

Comment: Refreshing provisioning profiles (step 4) is often the answer even if you aren't on a new machine.