# ios APNS issue xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using APNS in my ios application. I have tested APNS in debugging mode. Now when i am creating a build, the app is not able to Register For Remote Notification.

and it goes to *didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError* method.

Everything goes well when i connect device with xcode and test APNS, but when i create a build and install it to my device, i am getting below error:

*no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found fot application. code=3000*

Any solution?

## Update

My app always uses wild card profile to generate IPA file, dont know why.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324020/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application-on-app-store

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707063/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application-when-trying

Comment: @JimRhodes i have already had a look to both links, it didnt work for me.

Comment: Do you have an Entitlements.plist file in your project? If so, does it have an item named 'aps-environment'?

Comment: No, i dont have Entitlements.plist in my project. Is it mandatory to have "Entitlements.plist"?

Comment: For APNS, you must have a plist file with an item named 'aps-environment' in it and a value of either 'development' or 'production'.

Comment: should this value be in info.plist file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87037/discussion-between-alap-anerao-and-jim-rhodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete wild card profile and refresh xCode from preferences.